# puppet apply is working but puppet agent --test is not working?

Tags: puppet

I wrote a simple manifest test.pp

```
node'c-d'{ user{'abc': ensure=>absent, }

notify{'Notifying to client':}

}
```

But when i am trying to run it on agent node, its configuration is not getting applied , output is as under. Node c-d

```
[output] Info: Retrieving plugin Info: Caching catalog for <c-d.domain.com> Info: Applying configuration version '1420702685' Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.03 seconds
```

Note: puppetmaster and agent version is 3.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The master uses the central manifest as configured, see

```
puppet master --configprint manifest
```

This file will be used and searched for `node` definitions.

Specifically you cannot

1. Use just any arbitrary name and location for your manifest nor
2. Put the manifest onto the agent machine (which would be the way to use `puppet apply`).

Answer (score 0):

First you need make sure the setting between puppet master and agent has no issue, so that's mean when you run `puppet agent -t` for many times, no issue.

Then if you need apply the change through `puppet agent -t` on agent, then you need put `test.pp` to on puppet master under path `$mondulepath`. But from your description, you copy the file to agent directly.

So in this case, If you'd like to apply it directly on agent, run the command:

```
puppet apply --modulepath=/path/to/modules test.pp
```

Answer (score 0):

As @FelixFrank said, you can use *'config print'* to print where you will put your puppet code. What I used here was, print *'environmentpath'*, which says what is the path of the environments, the default environment is 'production'.

So, the default `init.pp` path is `$environmentpath/production/manifests/init.pp`